# Gnuplot: point size units

Tags: plot, gnuplot

How can I set the point size in gnuplot in the units of the plot coordinates?

In other words, the points should get smaller if I increase xrange.

It looks like this is all terminal dependent. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small example using inline data ...

```
plot '-' u 1:2:1 ps variable
  1 2
  2 3
  3 4
  4 5
  5 6
  e
```

Note that while it is possible to change the pointsize using a column from your datafile, I am not aware of any way to specify how large each point should be since the pointsize (and even the pointtype) is a terminal dependent quantity.  The only workaround that I can come up with is to scale the points by a terminal dependent value.

```
default_value=1.0
func(x)=1.0*x  #Change this to change the functional dependence of the pointsize on x.
scale_point(x)=(GPVAL_TERM=="postscript") ? 1.0*func(x) :\
               (GPVAL_TERM=="png") ?        2.0*(x) :\
               default_value
plot "mydata.dat" u 1:2:(scale_point($1)) w pt ps variable
```

It's ugly, but it should get the job done -- You could also write a similar function which returns the pointtype to achieve some sort of terminal independence with that as well...

**EDIT**

Note, my points *increase* in size linearly as x gets bigger, but you can substitute any function you want to make the points get smaller as you see fit.
What I am saying is that I don't believe that option exists since as you state "all this is terminal dependent".  I tried to provide a ugly hack to allow you to modify this on a per-plot basis with minimal intervention -- allowing for different terminals, etc.

**EDIT 2**

While responding to your comment, I remembered an odd little corner of the gnuplot documentation that may be helpful.

```
set style fill transparent solid noborder  #whatever fillstyle you want...
plot 'mydata' u 1:2:3 w circles
```

see `help circles` ... I'm not sure when this feature was introduced, probably with gnuplot 4.3, but if you're using 4.2 then give it a try and let me know how it goes...

Comment: That is not the answer to what I was asking. I know how to make the point size variable. I don't know how to specify the size in the coordinate system that gnuplot calls 'first'.

Comment: I know.  What I am saying is that I don't believe that option exists since as you state "all this is terminal dependent".  I tried to provide a ugly hack to allow you to modify this on a per-plot basis with minimal intervention -- allowing for different terminals, etc.

Comment: @hanno, apparently I spoke too soon and it is possible (at least if you want your points to appear as circles).  See my second update.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. That's what I've been looking for.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the question -- I learned something new too!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want the pointsize to be a decreasing function of the xrange. Exactly how big the points are printed and what they look like does depend on the terminal. But it's not hard to get the basic behavior that you want.

First, define a function to return the pointsize. Let's try

```
sps(a,b) = 1./(b-a)
```

Set your xrange:

```
set xrange [0:3]
```

Make a plot that you won't use:

```
plot sin(X)
```

We did that in order to get some of gnuplot's special variables defined. Now we can do

```
plot sin(x) with points pt 7 ps sps(GPVAL_X_MIN, GPVAL_X_MAX)
```

If you now reset the xrange and re-enter *both* plot commands, you will see that the pointsize changes, inversely proportional to the xrange. You probably want a different function for pointsize than the "sps" example that I used. I hope this is something like what you were after.

Comment: for making plots that you won't use, may I suggest the `unknown` terminal?  I'm guessing that's it's entire purpose.  However, I'm pretty sure the author of the question wants fine control over the pointsize.